# How to Play Animation in Unity using c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**unity 2d Animation in Gameobject.**

I have created in `one.anim` and `optionOne.controller` its controller configured in that GameObject [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZDlK.png). how to play that Animation using c#. I'm a beginner so please help me for that. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [Unity Animation Tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation). They will explain it best.